# Null reference exception while try casting controls

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to cast a menu item to rich text box and it is throwing a null reference exception.

The code is

```
' ensure above it true and find parent
Dim mnuItem As MenuItem = TryCast(sender, MenuItem)
If mnuItem IsNot Nothing Then
  Dim menu As Menu = TryCast(mnuItem.Parent, Menu)
  If menu IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim rtb As RichTextBox = TryCast(menu.Container, RichTextBox)
    If rtb IsNot Nothing Then
      rtb.Copy()
    End If
  End If
End If
```

The code throws an exception at the line rtb.Copy(). Can anyone please guide me in the right direction on how to resolve this?

Edit : It shows rbt as 'Nothing' when I step through the code.

Comment: I think you mean `IsNot`

Comment: I did not post the correct code before.

Comment: When you have to write code like the above, chances are something is wrong with your design.

Answer (score 1):

`menu.container` in `Dim rtb As RichTextBox = TryCast(menu.Container, RichTextBox)` is probably not a RichTextBox. With the debugger, stop at that line, highlight "menu.container", and press Shift-F9 to see what it really is.

Answer (score 0):

It says "IsNothing" where you mean to test for not nothing.

```
If rtb Is Nothing Then
    rtb.Copy()
End If
```

should be:

```
If rtb IsNot Nothing Then
    rtb.Copy()
End If
```

Comment: Thanks Mark.  I did it too. But still throwing an excpetion.

Comment: What exception does it throw now?

Comment: When I include 'If rtb IsNot Nothing' it does not go to the line 'rtb.Copy'.

Comment: In that case, it wasn't able to cast Menu.container to a rich text box. So in that sense "it works". I noticed on MSDN an example also had a test for "If rtb.SelectionLength > 0" before trying to do the copy(). Not sure if that would throw a null reference, but it seems a logical check anyway. I would look more closely at why Menu.Container doesn't cast. Are you sure it's a RichTextBox or related class?

Comment: I am sure it is RichTextBox.

Comment: Use the debugger to see what it is.

Comment: When I use the debugger it display rtb As Nothing at line `Dim rtb As RichTextBox = TryCast(menu.Container, RichTextBox)`

Comment: In the debugger you must look what the type of `menu.Container` is.

Comment: I checked for `menu.Container` in the debugger and it is also `Nothing`

Comment: If `menu.Container` is `Nothing`, then that is the definite reason, why `rtb` is also `Nothing` (casting `Nothing` in something else always remains `Nothing`). In the end it means, that `menu` has no container -- you must find another way to get the `RichTextBox` you want, or redesign your form so that the textbox becomes the container of `menu`.